# How to pass an argument to a method on a template variable in Django?

Tags: django, templates

I am using the lxml library to define a variable (category) in a view. lxml provides a method `.get` to retrieve custom attributes. I'd like to use it in the template like so:

```
{{ category.get("foo") }}
```

I know that when using template variables it is unnecessary to use parenthesis, but I get the following error:

```
{{ category.get "foo" }}
```

> Could not parse the remainder: ' "foo"' from 'category.get "foo"'

I'm assuming that there is something wrong with my syntax but google has been no help. The django docs say that methods are looked up by using a `.`

Comment: The syntax used in Django template filters is ":" for arguments, so I think if someone were to implement this, it would be {{ category.get:foo }}.  But, it doesn't exist.  Maybe you should add it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call function that takes an argument in a Django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468804/how-to-call-function-that-takes-an-argument-in-a-django-template)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't pass an argument to a callable attribute like this.  Either pull the value in the view, or write a custom template tag to do it.

Comment: Is there any way to have access to other variables, like the current request (i.e. request.user) or the current context object?

Comment: you can in a custom templatetag

Answer (score 15):

I agree with the philosophy of separating logic from design, but there's an exception. I am currently writing a get_image(height=xxx, width=xxx) method for a model. Clearly, it should be up to the template designer to decide the size of the image as the last stage. Though I suppose the correct thing to do is write a custom tag, but why restrict?

Comment: Totally true. It's not an "answer", more like a comment, but +1

Answer (score 12):

Here I wrote a hack to call a function and pass the arguments
http://www.sprklab.com/notes/13-passing-arguments-to-functions-in-django-template/

Comment: This looks somehow like mixing code and content, almost the same way PHP does that. What do you think?