# How to pass an argument to a function in html

Tags: python, html, function, django-templates

My models.py:

```
class Aff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ...

    def somefunction(self, variable):
        #something
        return result

    def somefunction2(self):
        #something
        return result
```

My template.html:

```
{% for a in aff_list %}
    {{ a.somefunction(var) }}
{% endfor %}
```

It gives this error: `Could not parse the remainder: '(var)' from 'a.somefunction(var)'`. somefunction2 instead works. Maybe it's a stupid question but I can't find the solution and it's some hours that I work on it, so someone can help me please?

Comment: note: html has no functions.

Comment: There are several answered questions about not being able to pass arguments to functions in Django templates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2468804/3901060, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1419183/3901060.

Comment: Thank you, I found only answers about javascript function!